# React native paper card with an image background

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo, react-native-paper

Result I want to get:

[image]

Result I got:

[image]

I would like to get the example you see in the image above, with the image as the background of the card.
And the texts of the card as seen in the first image.

Can you give me a hand?

Link expo: [link](https://snack.expo.dev/2TmI6_5Mz)

Code:

```js
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Card, Chip } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Card style={{}}>
        <Card.Cover
          source={{
            uri: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a7/React-icon.svg/1200px-React-icon.svg.png',
          }}
        />
        <Card.Title title={'React native'} />
        <Card.Content>
          <Text variant="bodyMedium">2 hours ago</Text>
          <Chip
            style={{
              backgroundColor: '#1faeb3',
            }}>
            Ep 4
          </Chip>
        </Card.Content>
      </Card>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: 30,
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

Comment: All the components used work as intended. If you want to get the desired result, you should wrap your title and content in a separate view with an absolute position (`position:'absolute'`) and then style it according to your project.